# Wait an asynchronous callback - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, callback

I had some trouble with CLLocationManager callbacks
What is the best way to wait an asynchronous callback ?

Here is what i basically want to do :

```
 

- (NSString *)getCurrentCity 
{
       [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
       // Wait for coordonate in callbacks
       self.geocoder = [MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordonate:self.newCoordonate];
       [self.geocoder start];
       // Wait for information with MKReverse callbacks
       return self.currentCity;
}
// Callbacks methods of MKReverseGeocoder and CLLocationManager
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     idUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
        CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoordonate = newLocation.coordinate;
        self.currentCoordonate = &newCoordonate;
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder 
       didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark 
{
       self.currentCity = placemark.locality;
}
```

Where self.currentCity and self.newCoordonate is an attribut in my classe.

I tried some tricks like Thread and/or synchronized but i didn't managed it to dont return before all is finish.

Best regards

Comment: self.currentCoordonate = &newCoordonate; That scares me on a number of levels

Comment: The whole point of async callback is that you don't have to wait for it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't wait for it to complete, you handle the update when the asynchronous `locationmanager:didUpdatefromLocation:` is called. That's the point of asynchronous programming. :)

Comment: I agree; in fact . I juste want to call a method to get one information by passing through async callbacks. And if I could pass it synch i would be nice for me i think

Comment: A way could be to write a wrapper class `GPSManager` or something like that. It would handle the `CLLocationManager` stuff and expose two properties like `positionAvailable` and `currentPosition` for use in your other code.

Comment: Ive already tried that but its the same point... How know if my property has changed ? It work asynchronously too.

Comment: Well, then you want an asynchronous callback anyway, so no problem...?

Answer (score 1):

Any time you block the main thread, your app becomes unresponsive (at best) and will get jettisoned by the system (i.e. killed -- in the worst case).

For asynchronous APIs, the easiest pattern is to isolate *all* of the threading or queueing or whatever mechanism you use to get the work off the main thread into a class that takes care of rendezvousing back to the main thread as needed.

For an example, look at `NSFileHandle`.  It has a `readInBackgroundAndNotify:` method.  When used, the `NSFileHandle` instance internally creates a thread, uses that thread to read whatever is needed, then uses something like `performSelectorOnThread:` to send the notification to the thread -- typically the main thread -- that called `readInBackgroundAndNotify:` in the first place.

By doing this, users of the class don't have to deal with the threading *but* the class doesn't block the main event loop.

---

BTW:

```
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoordinate = newLocation.coordinate;
    self.currentCoordonate = &newCoordinate;
}
```

This is completely wrong and a sure fire way to guarantee a crash or undefined behavior.  `&newCoordinate` gives the address of `newCoordinate`, but that structure is on the stack.  As soon as that method returns, the contents of said structure are going to be trashed.

Comment: i do that because i declare a pointer of CLLocationCoordinate2D. So CLLocationCoordinate2D *newCoordinate = &newCoordinate; work perfectly

Comment: @KL94: Yes, it's a pointer, and sure, your code is accepted by Objective-C's type system. There's more to a working program than making sure your types match. Taking a pointer to an automatic variable and storing it in an instance variable is undefined behavior — it's a bug or a crash waiting to happen. Questions to ask yourself to find the right solution: *Why* is that instance variable a pointer? If there's a reason it needs to be, what is that reason? You need to design your code properly around that constraint. Otherwise, don't make it a pointer.